# Downloading PDF files from webserver using JS, and save them on iOS 7

Tags: javascript, ios, pdf, download, mobile-safari

Our customer has several iPad with iOS 7, and they can't upgrade their iOS.
So we face a situation with the deprecated safari browser.

With this limitation, our **web application** should download several PDF files from the webserver, and save them somehow on the client (iPad).

We try to solve this problem by downloading each PDF file as a `blob` with mime type: `application/pdf`, but now we can't save them anywhere in iOS 7, because we don't have access to the file system on the Safari. 
Is there any solution to access to other services like iCloud or even iBook to save those PDF files?

If you think we choose a completely wrong path to solve this problem, please tell us.

Comment: can you store pdf in iPhone's photo gallery?

Comment: @Mahendra could you tell me how?

Comment: @dahiya_boy, It is clear in the question that the problem is within a web application not in a native app.